# Enum support for swagger doc

Tags: enums, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am a little confused by Swagger's enum support for OpenAPI3.0. My point here being that there have been new improvements in swagger doc where there is support for re-usable enums as 
documented here:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/

where support for reusable enums is stated using $ref. However, when I post my swagger.json to swagger editor/validator which looks like following

```
in: query
          name: prop-name
          description: something
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/definitions/mytype'
```

which is further defined below:

```
mytype:
    enum:
      - Item1
    type: string
```

Swagger editor throws an error and says `should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: $ref`

Now, this is not a problem when loading the swagger page and attaining the functionality but it is an issue when it comes to using swagger-gen and generating clients using it. the swagger-gen CLI also throws the same error causing us to now being able to generate a client for this page correctly.

Is there anything wrong with this swagger.json? I there any extra information that I can provide to shed light on this issue?

Comment: Do you use `swagger: '2.0'` or `openapi: 3.0.0`?

Comment: I used swagger 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenAPI 2.0, array parameter schemas cannot use `$ref`. You must define the `enum` inline:

```yaml
- in: query
  name: prop-name
  description: something
  type: array
  items:
    type: string
    enum:
      - Item1
```